# Errors in Vectorized For-loop Matlab Code

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, parfor

I have a for loop code which I want to vectorize. Below is the initial for loop code, and the vectorized version of the code. The vectorized code isn't giving the same result as that of the parfor loop, hence I know something is wrong with the code. I would appreciate it if any member of the forum can help me review the vectorized code and see if they can point out my errors to me. Thank you in advance.

% Initialization and precomputations
% w is an n x 1 vector
% beta: any number larger than 0. Usually set to 1.
Here is the for-loop code I need to vectorize:

```
f = zeros(n,1);
x = w;
y = w;
rho = 1;
v = f – (rho*y);
rhow = rho*w;
n = length(w);

parfor i = 1 : n

if w(i) >= 0
    if v(i) < -rhow(i) – beta – 1
        x(i) = (-beta -1 -v(i))/rho;

    elseif (-rhow(i) – beta – 1 <= v(i)) && (v(i) <= -rhow(i) + beta – 1)
        x(i) = w(i);

    elseif (-rhow(i) + beta – 1 < v(i)) && (v(i) < beta – 1)
        x(i) = (beta – 1 -v(i))/rho;

    elseif (beta – 1 <= v(i)) && (v(i) <= beta + 1)
        x(i) = 0;

    else
        x(i) = (beta + 1 – v(i))/rho;
    end

else

    if v(i) < -beta -1
        x(i) = (-beta -1 – v(i))/rho;

    elseif (-beta – 1 <= v(i) )&& (v(i) <= -beta + 1)
        x(i) = 0;

    elseif (-beta + 1 < v(i)) && (v(i) < -rhow(i) – beta + 1)
        x(i) = (-beta + 1 – v(i))/rho;

    elseif (-rhow(i) – beta + 1 <= v(i)) && (v(i) <= -rhow(i) + beta + 1)
        x(i) = w(i);

    else
        x(i) = (beta + 1 – v(i))/rho;
    end

end
```

end

======================================================================

And here is my vectorized version of the code above:

```
cond1 = (w >= 0);
cond2 = (w >= 0) & (v < -rhow-beta-1);       
x(cond2) = (-beta-1-v(cond2))/rho; 

cond3 = (w>=0)&(-rhow - beta -1 <= v) & (v <= -rhow + beta - 1);
x(cond3) =  w(cond3);

cond4 = (w>=0) & (-rhow +beta - 1 < v) & (v < beta - 1);
x(cond4) = (beta - 1 - v(cond4))/rho;

cond5 = (w>=0) & (beta - 1 <= v) & (v <= beta + 1);
x(cond5) = 0;

cond6 = (~cond2);
x(cond6) = (beta + 1 - v(cond6))/rho;

cond7 = ((~cond1) & v < -beta -1);
x(cond7) = (-beta -1 - v(cond7))/rho;

cond8 = ((~cond1) & (-beta - 1 <= v) & (v <= -beta + 1));
x(cond8) = 0;

cond9 = ((~cond1) & (-beta + 1 < v) & (v < -rhow - beta + 1));
x(cond9) = (-beta + 1 - v(cond9))/rho;

cond10 = ((~cond1) & (-rhow - beta + 1 <= v) & (v <= -rhow + beta + 1));
x(cond10) = w(cond10);

cond11 = (~cond1);
x(cond11) = (beta + 1 - v(cond11))/rho;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding another answer with all the conditionals checked:

```
cond1 = (w >= 0);
cond2 = cond1 & (v < -rhow – beta – 1);
cond3 = cond1 & ((-rhow – beta – 1 <= v) && (v <= -rhow + beta – 1));
cond4 = cond1 & ((-rhow + beta – 1 < v) && (v < beta – 1));
cond5 = cond1 & ((beta – 1 <= v) && (v <= beta + 1));
cond6 = cond1 & (v > beta + 1)

cond7 = ~cond1 & (v < -beta -1);
cond8 = ~cond1 & ((-beta – 1 <= v ) && (v <= -beta + 1));
cond9 = ~cond1 & ((-beta + 1 < v) && (v < -rhow – beta + 1));
cond10 = ~cond1 & ((-rhow – beta + 1 <= v) && (v <= -rhow + beta + 1));
cond11 = ~cond1 & (v > -rhow + beta + 1);
```

x(cond2)=... to x(cond11)=... remain the same.
Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one mistake, cond6 is not equivalent to the original first `else`

```
cond2 = (w >= 0) & (v < -rhow-beta-1);
cond6 = (~cond2);
x(cond6) = (beta + 1 - v(cond6))/rho;
```

in the original this is:

```
if w(i) >= 0
   if v(i) < -rhow(i) – beta – 1
      ...
   else
      x(i) = (beta + 1 – v(i))/rho;  %this should be cond6
   end
end
```

The else should be evaluated like this (If I'm not mistaken)

```
x(cond1) = (beta + 1 - v(cond6))/rho;
```

and before all the others up to cond5.

I did not check all the code, so if this doesn't solve your problem let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I'm not sure what you mean by "before all others up to cond5". But I tried to implement what I understood from what you said, but I'm still getting errors.                                                                                                 cond1 = (w >= 0);
    cond2 = (cond1) & (v < -rhow-beta-1); 
    x = ((-beta-1-v(cond2))/rho) | ((beta + 1 - v(~cond2))/rho)

Comment: I meant that this condition should be evaluated first, before x(cond2) to x(cond5).  If you do it after any of those, x(cond1) will overwrite them.